# Не могу найти ошибку в табуляции

Tags: python, discord.py, tab

Я хотел сделать постаянное изменение статуса бота, но в итоге получил ошибку:

```
  File "main.py", line 28
    while True:
TabError: inconsistent use of tabs and spaces in indentation
```

Сам код:

```
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print("\n[INFO]    Бот запущен!")
  
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.dnd, activity = discord.Activity(name = f' !ping ', type = discord.ActivityType.playing)) 
        time.sleep(15)
        await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.dnd, activity = discord.Activity(name = f'на Ваши нервы ;)', type = discord.ActivityType.watching))
        time.sleep(15)
```

Вроде табуляция в коде верна, а  все равно пишет эту ошибку... Как так?

Comment: После while должно быть тоже 2-а пробела, а не 4-е

Comment: Спасибо большое, а то я везде искал, понять не мог)

Comment: Вот ваша ошибка: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WU9ZX.png Стрелки - это символы табуляции. Никогда не смешивайте табы и пробелы, а еще лучше - используйте только пробелы для отступов.